# Magento 2 Mail Queue / log

Tags: email, magento-2.1.8

Does Magento 2 log mails to the database?

i.e. where did Magento 1's core_email_queue go?

Does it make a difference if Sales Emails -> Asynchronous sending is enabled?

Answer (score 6):

Magento 2 doens't have this feature by default but you can use this free plugin, which catches the emails in the database table `experius_emailcatcher` :

**Magento 2 Module Experius Email Catcher**

*Email Catcher / Logger Module for Magento 2.*

```
System > Tools > Email Catcher
```

Disables all email communications when system/smpt/disable is Yes.

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-Email-Catcher